# Compare string to multiple strings

Tags: php

I'm trying to find a better way to compare a string against multiple strings in an if statement - where $f is a file name or directory -

```
if (id_dir($f) && $f != "." && $f != "..") echo ($f);
```

I tried the following to avoid having the second && statement -

```
if (is_dir($f) && ! in_array($f, array('..','.'))) echo($f);
```

but, obviously that's even more convoluted. Is there a better way to compare a string to multiple strings.

Comment: in_array() is the quickest if all you need is a simple equality test check. If you're worried about the array version being a few characters longer, you're MASSIVELy overoptimizing and focused on the wrong thing. just because a chunk of of code is "longer" than another has absolutely NO relation to how fast/slow that longer code would actually execute

Comment: What does shortness have to do with anything? You don't get bonus points for making you code as short as possible. You should strive to make it as clearly understandable and maintainable as possible.

Comment: Honestly, that code is fine? Checking it's not parent or a self reference is pretty standard. Even in the official PHP examples they do that(http://au1.php.net/readdir)

Comment: Efficient would have been a better word - or maybe understandability. The in_array method is a bit convoluted, perhaps it would be better if I defined the array outside of the if statement.

Comment: Thanks guys, I updated the question. Though I think I have my answer.

Comment: @unclemeat To clarify things a little better, doing the first check with `&&` and `&&` is better because you don't have the overhead of creating an array and then traversing through it. You are doing a simple string comparison which is VERY fast. The only way to see a benefit would be to loop thousands and thousands of times, but the top one would be faster. There's no need to create more data structures, that just uses more memory!